# combine blocks of code to one function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dry

How can I make one function to do something like this

```
$('#check_express').is(':checked') ? $('#form_express').show() : $('#form_express').hide();

$('#check_express').on('change', function(){
    $(this).is(':checked') ? $('#form_express').show() : 
    $('#form_express').hide();
});

$('#check_standard').is(':checked') ? $('#form_standard').show() : $('#form_standard').hide();

$('#check_standard').on('change', function(){
    $(this).is(':checked') ? $('#form_standard').show() : 
    $('#form_standard').hide();
});
```

Comment: Add your `html` too.

Comment: my html is too big, its on ruby on rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can extract the code into a function

```
function bind_stuff(type) {
  $('#check_' + type).is(':checked') ? $('#form_' + type).show() : $('#form_' + type).hide();

  $('#check_' + type).on('change', function(){
      $(this).is(':checked') ? $('#form_' + type).show() : 
      $('#form_' + type).hide();
  });
}

bind_stuff('express');
bind_stuff('standard');
```

You can then shorten the show/hide-Parts by using toggle, which takes an optional boolean parameter which indicates whether to show or hide:

```
function bind_stuff(type) {
  $('#form_' + type).toggle($('#check_' + type).is(':checked'));

  $('#check_' + type).on('change', function(){
      $('#form_' + type).toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
  });
}
bind_stuff('express');
bind_stuff('standard');
```

If you want to go further, you can reduce the initializing part by faking an change event:

```
function bind_stuff(type) {
  $('#check_' + type).on('change', function(){
      $('#form_' + type).toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
  });
  $('#check_' + type).trigger('change');
}

bind_stuff('express');
bind_stuff('standard');
```

Comment: Since you are passing `type` to the function, you don't really need `on('change'` .. Only have `$('#form_' + type).toggle($(this).is(':checked'));`.. Having a function and an event trigger inside the function defeats the entire purpose.

Comment: i want to achieve two things: 1) initialize the state of the forms and 2) keep them in sync afterwards. if it is ensured that the initial state of the forms is in sync with the state of the checkboxes then the trigger is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably merge them as:

```
$('#check_standard,#check_express').on('change', function() {
  var selectedId = this.id;
  var getName = selectedId.split('_');
  $(this).is(':checked') ? $('#form_' + getName[1]).show() :
    $('#form_' + getName[1]).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) like following :

```js
$('#check_express').on('change', function() {
  $('#form_express').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="check_express" />
<div id="form_express" style="display: none">
  Hello, world.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would bind one function to both selectors.

In the function, check which `id` is triggered.

The toggle the visibility by using `toggle( expression )`. Where expression checks if the the checkbox is checked (=show) or not (=hide).

```js
$('#check_express,#check_standard').on('change', function(){
    if( this.id == 'check_express' ) {
        $('#form_express').toggle( $(this).is(':checked') );
    }
    else {
        $('#form_standard').toggle( $(this).is(':checked') );
    }    
});
```

```css
form { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Check express: <input type="checkbox" id="check_express" /> <br />
Check standard: <input type="checkbox" id="check_standard" /> <br />

<form id="form_express">
  Form express
</form>
<form id="form_standard">
  Form standard
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend having a map of checkbox ID vs. form to do it at one shot:

```
var map = {
  check_express: $('#form_express'),
  check_standard: $('#form_standard')
};

$('#check_express, #check_standard').on('change', function() {
    map[this.id].toggle($(this).is(':checked')); 
});
```

In case you have more such cases, simply add them to `map`.